# Jmeter Test Plan summary report PASS/FAIL

Tags: jmeter

I'm stuck on finding solution on one problem with Jmeter. I need to put some logic into my Test Plan that can give simple report PASS/FAIL calculated on test cases execution results and put in generated JTL report afterwards. For instance

1. All tests passed - Test Plan result=PASS
2. One or more tests failed - Test Plan result=FAIL

Comment: you can use error percentage field available in Aggregate Report/Summary Report listeners. If error % = 0, then All tests passed, otherwise, fail.

Answer (score 0):

The majority of suitable options assume using third-party tools, to wit:

- you can run JMeter test in [Jenkins](http://jenkins.io/) and use Performance plugin, it allows to conditionally fail the build if the amount of failed requests exceeds specified threshold

  [image: Jenkins performance plugin]
- you can run JMeter test using [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/) tool as a wrapper, it has flexible and powerful [Pass/Fail Criteria Subsystem](http://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) allowing to set different criteria definitions to mark the test as passed or failed. If build is failed Taurus process returns non-zero exit code.

If above approaches are not suitable for any reason please elaborate your question and explain how and where you would like to see this "FAIL" or "PASS" result.

Comment: Hi Dmitri,

so here is the main goal of this exercise, I want to send with mail message after test execution the overall Test Plan result as subject/body message.

Comment: At first I thought it could be somehow extracted from the JTL report and then put in ant mail task.

Comment: Again there are several options of doing this. If you want Ant - you could use [XPath Task](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2009/05/17/perform-xpath-queries-inside-ant/) to get the number of failures and [If Task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/if.html) to conditionally set property to PASS or FAIL. Other option is sending an email directly from JMeter using [SMTP Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-your-email-server-how-send-and-receive-e-mails-jmeter).

Comment: First approach works for me but it is only for request successful/failed. I need to fail the test depending on average response time as well. I tried the second approach you suggested on your answer to set a threshold of 200ms for the `avg-rt`. The test exits with code `3` but instead of failing, the test is flagged as unstable.

Answer (score 0):

Add one BeanShell Listener and one BeanShell Sampler at the end of your Thread Group and put this in Listener:

```
if(sampleEvent.getResult() instanceof org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSampleResult)
    if (!sampleEvent.getResult().isResponseCodeOK())
            vars.put("res", -1);
```

And in BS Sampler put:

- if you wanna store result as property:

> `props.put("testPlanResult", vars.get("res") != -1 ? "PASS" : "FAIL");`

- if you wanna store result in a file:

> ```
> f = new FileOutputStream("/path/to/file.txt", false);
> p = new PrintStream(f); 
>
> p.println("Result: " + (vars.get("res") != -1 ? "PASS" : "FAIL"));
>
> p.close();
> f.close();
> ```

From here you can do what ever you need with created property or file containing result...

Hope this helps you!

EDIT:

You will need to add this import if writing result to file:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;
```